# Jquery slideUp not working

Tags: jquery

slideUp is not working when clicking on div object.

Jquery code:

```
$('#show-about-btn').click(function() {
    $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9660;");
    if($('.menu-nav').css('display')=='none') {
        $('.menu-nav').slideDown("fast").show();
    } else {
        $('.menu-nav').slideUp().hide();
        $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9650;");
    }
});
```

Full code is here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/yfgxwmm7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `.show()` and `.hide()` when you `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()`.

```
$('#show-about-btn').click(function() {
    $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9660;");
    if($('.menu-nav').css('display')=='none') {
        $('.menu-nav').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.menu-nav').slideUp();
        $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9650;");
    }
});
```

Fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfgxwmm7/1/).

Comment: Thanks ,as i understand slideUp/Down, have a default option of hide and show

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in show and hide methods. Remove it.

```
if($('.menu-nav').css('display')=='none') {
    $('.menu-nav').slideDown();
} else {
    $('.menu-nav').slideUp();
    $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9650;");
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfgxwmm7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, I think it's working -

```js
$('#show-about-btn').click(function() {
 $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9660;");
 if($('.menu-nav').css('display')=='none') {
  $('.menu-nav').slideDown();
 } else {
  $('.menu-nav').slideUp();
  $('#show-about-btn').html("&#9650;");
 }
});
```

```css
.subnav li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 1px 60px 1px 1px;
}

.subnav {
 max-width: 600px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 3em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tab{
 position: relative;
 top: 25px;
 width: 600px;
}

.menu-nav {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><h1 class="title">Link</a><a href="#" id="show-about-btn">&#9650;</a></h1>

<div class="menu-nav"> 
     <nav class="subnav">
      <ul class="tabs">
       <li><a href="#portfolio" class="active">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#about_us">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul> 
     </nav>

  <div class="sub-content">  
   <article>
    <div class="tab" id="portfolio">
     <p>1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, nisi quidem saepe, minus qui amet officiis voluptatum odio maiores sunt blanditiis nostrum eum. Animi placeat aut magni, quo magnam harum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="about_us">
     <p>2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, nisi quidem saepe, minus qui amet officiis voluptatum odio maiores sunt blanditiis nostrum eum. Animi placeat aut magni, quo magnam harum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="contact_us">
     <p>3.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, nisi quidem saepe, minus qui amet officiis voluptatum odio maiores sunt blanditiis nostrum eum. Animi placeat aut magni, quo magnam harum.</p>
    </div>
   </article>
  </div> 
 </div>
```